# How an increase in a numeric variable affects another numeric variable in R using the estimated regression line equation

Tags: r, regression

I would like to know how much could a 0.2 increase in `whr`, affect the `age`  (with 95% CI)? Disaggregated by `sex` and if increase in males and females is significantly different.

I have already followed this [link](https://rpubs.com/mdlama/171049) but I do not know how to answer the original question. Any guidance?

I guess I should find the estimated regression line equation

My data:

```
age<-c(50,48,45,56,46,37,56,67,45,36)
whr<-c(0.9,0.87,0.76,0.9,0.76,0.78,0.89,0.85,0.98,0.9)
sex<-c("F","M","M","F","M","M","F","M","M","F")
dataset<-data.frame(age,whr,sex)

age  whr sex
1   50 0.90   F
2   48 0.87   M
3   45 0.76   M
4   56 0.90   F
5   46 0.76   M
6   37 0.78   M
7   56 0.89   F
8   67 0.85   M
9   45 0.98   M
10  36 0.90   F
```

Comment: Yes: *look at the data.*  One way is with a scatterplot that distinguishes the sexes, as in `with(dataset, plot(age, whr, pch=ifelse(sex=="F", 1, 19)))`

Comment: thanks could you explain how this answers how could a 0.2 increase in whr affects the age?

Comment: This scatterplot shows there is no consistent pattern and that even a linear fit will reveal no association between `whr` and `age`.

Comment: Yes but these are toy data. I guess that my question has to do with the estimated regression line equation. This is the one I should find.

Comment: Given we can infer nothing from your example, you need to tell us, then, more about what you mean by "nonlinear," because that could refer to literally any model.

Comment: Nevermind the nonlinear. I think I should do domething like this to find the regression equation http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/40-regression-analysis/167-simple-linear-regression-in-r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your "nevermind..." comment I take it, that simple linear regression aka ordinary least squares is fine. You might start like this:

```
age<-c(50,48,45,56,46,37,56,67,45,36)
whr<-c(0.9,0.87,0.76,0.9,0.76,0.78,0.89,0.85,0.98,0.9)
sex<-c("F","M","M","F","M","M","F","M","M","F")
dataset<-data.frame(age,whr,sex, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

model <- lm(age ~ whr + sex + sex*whr, data = dataset)
print(summary(model)$coefficients)
```

the `model <- ...` line defines a linear model with 4 coefficients, the values, standard errors and p-values of which aber then printed in the `print(...` line. The meaning of the results is:

`Intercept`gives the intercept for females, `(Intercept) + sexM` gives the intercept for males. `whr` gives how much `age` increases for females when `whr`increases by `1`. You can multiply that bei `0.2` for your question.
`whr + whr:sexM` gives the slope for males. If `whr:sexM` is significant, i. e. if it's `Pr(>|t|)` value is below `0.05` we consider that a significantly different slope for males then for females.

In the table printed with `print(summary(model)$coefficients)` you'll find the standard errors of the coefficient which can be the basis to compute the CIs you are looking for.

All the data on the regression from the link you gabe can be inspected via `summary(fit)`.

Comment: Tnx.So I should multiply -866.6667 with 0.2

Comment: If that was the whr coefficient with your real data and we're talking females here, yes.

Comment: Tnx I will ask a similar Q later.

Comment: Based on your instructions I created a new one https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484741/how-much-an-increase-in-a-numeric-variable-affects-a-categorical-variable