# How much an increase in a numeric variable affects a categorical variable?

Tags: r, regression

For a 0.2 increase in `whr`, what is the associated increase in age adjusted diabetes prevalence (with 95% CI)? Disaggregated by sex and if increase in males and females is significantly different. Here is my dataset and my glm model.

```
age<-c(50,48,45,56,46,37,56,67,45,36)
whr<-c(0.9,0.87,0.76,0.9,0.76,0.78,0.89,0.85,0.98,0.9)
sex<-c("F","M","M","F","M","M","F","M","M","F")
diabetes<-c("1","0","1","1","0","1","1","0","1","1")
dataset<-data.frame(age,whr,sex,diabetes)

library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
training.samples <- dataset$diabetes %>% 
  createDataPartition(p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train.data  <- dataset[training.samples, ]
test.data <- dataset[-training.samples, ]

model <- glm( diabetes ~ whr, data = train.data, family = binomial)
summary(model)$coef



Estimate Std. Error    z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -6.847636   9.232514 -0.7416871 0.4582769
whr          8.900307  10.949729  0.8128335 0.4163135
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the example is given above, it will work for R versions <4.0. Starting with 4.0 you need to add `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` in order to convert `diabetes` from string to factor. Or you need to `as.numeric` convert `diabetes`.

In the simple model you gave, an `0.2` increase in `whr` will increase the logodds of diabetes by `8.9 * 0.2`.

In order to age adjust you should compute

```
> model <- glm( diabetes ~ whr + age, data = train.data, family = binomial)
> summary(model)$coef
         Estimate Std. Error    z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -6.710273 11.3496870 -0.5912298 0.5543665
whr         18.006884 16.7853669  1.0727727 0.2833731
age         -0.155941  0.1317604 -1.1835195 0.2366033
```

Now obviously you should not try to compute 3 coefficients from 10 observations and the results are just random numbers, but for the sake of argument the point remains: The logodds of the probability of diabetes in this model is $-6.7 + 18.0*whr -0.15*age$ and thus increase by $18.0 * 0.2$ for each $0.2$ increase in `whr`.

Now a full model with constant effect of age but varying influence of wht per gender could theoretically be computed via

```
model <- glm( diabetes ~ whr*sex + age, data = train.data, family = binomial)
summary(model)
```

Now we are estimating 5 coefficients from 10 observations which will make R print a warning or two and will produce p values very near to 1.0:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  2.457e+03  3.637e+07   0.000    1.000
whr         -1.232e+02  4.048e+07   0.000    1.000
sexM        -5.953e+02  3.641e+07   0.000    1.000
age         -4.144e+01  2.712e+04  -0.002    0.999
whr:sexM     1.548e+02  4.058e+07   0.000    1.000
```

Obviously `whr:sexM`is not significant, so we have no proof of a different slope for men and `sexM` is not significant so we have no proof of a different Intercept for men.

Comment: tnx a lot.regarding the 2nd model how can I calculate the effect? with those toy results. -1.23*0.2?

Comment: Note that 1.23e+02 in computer notation is not 1.23 but $1.23*10^2$!